# Show that the sequence $f_{n}(x)=\sin nx$ does not have a convergent subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am currently trying to prove, that for $f_{n}\in C([0,2\pi])$ with $f_{n}=\sin nx$, that $f_n$ does not have a converging subsequence. I have seen proofs on this site, where the dominated convergence theorem is used. In my case I should find a correlation between the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^{\infty}}$-norm and the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^2}$-norm and I can't seem to find one.

I know that, if $f_n$ does have a subsequence $f_{n_k}$, then $\Vert f_{n_{k+1}}-f_{n_k} \Vert_{L^{\infty}}$ should converge to $0$ with $k\rightarrow\infty$. The problem is, that the supremum of $g_{n_k}(x):=f_{n_{k+1}}(x)-f_{n_k}(x)$ does not seem to be calculable. So my guess is that I should bound this with the $L_2$-norm, because $\Vert g_{n_k} \Vert_{L^{2}}=\sqrt{2\pi}$ for all $k$ but I don't know how.

Any help in furthering my progress would be appreciated.

Comment: Which concept of convergence do you have in mind?

Comment: Do you know about the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It isn't stated which convergence should be proven, but from my lecture I would guess uniform convergence.

Comment: @PCeltide We never learned about it in this course, but maybe in a previous one. I wanted to see if there is a way with relating my two stated norms, but maybe this implies that I should use the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: The simplest argument is based on the orthogonality. $$\sqrt{2\pi}=\|f_n-f_m\|_2 \\ \le 2\pi\|f_n-f_m\|_\infty$$ Hence no subsequence satisfies the Cauchy condition. No dominated theorem is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a very general fact which you should keep in mind.

> If $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ is a finite measure space, and $1\leq p < q\leq \infty$, then we have an continuous linear inclusion $\iota: L^q(\mu)\hookrightarrow L^p(\mu)$ with operator norm $\mu(X)^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}$.

In words this is saying that on a **finite** measure space, if you’re in a higher Lebesgue space, then you’re automatically inside all lower ones. In fact, the case $q=\infty$ is so obvious (and also the one relevant for your question) that we can give a one line proof:
\begin{align}
\|f\|_p^p&=\int_X|f|^p\,d\mu\leq\int_X\|f\|_{\infty}^p\,d\mu=\|f\|_{\infty}^p\cdot\mu(X).
\end{align}
Taking $1/p$ roots gives $\|f\|_p\leq \|f\|_{\infty}\cdot \mu(X)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\|f\|_{\infty}\cdot \mu(X)^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{\infty}}$. I leave it to you to prove the inequality in the cases $q<\infty$ (use Holder’s inequality with a clever choice of conjugate exponents), and that the operator norm really is equal to $\mu(X)^{\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{q}}$.

As a trivial corollary (well, essentially what continuity means), if $f_n\to f$ in $L^q(\mu)$, then $f_n\to f$ in $L^p(\mu)$.

---

In your case, take $(p,q)=(2,\infty)$: suppose $\{g_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $[0,2\pi]$ (which has finite measure) which converges to $0$ uniformly (hence $\|g_k\|_{\infty}\to 0$). The above remarks would imply that $g_k\to 0$ in $L^2([0,2\pi])$ as well; but if $\|g_k\|_{2}$ is a positive constant, then obviously this cannot converge to $0$. Thus, you deduce that $g_k$ does not converge to $0$ uniformly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! What you commented is really helpful, especially the inequality $||f||_{p}\leq \mu(X)^{\frac{1}{p}}||f||_{\infty}$. Wouldn't this already be sufficient, or am I missing something? Because, if there would be a uniformly converging subsequence $f_{n_k}$, then the $\infty$-norm of $g_{n_k}:=f_{n_{k+1}}-f_{n_k}$ would approach $0$ for $k\rightarrow\infty$. With this inequality, we would have $||g_{n_k}||_{2}\leq\mu([0,2\pi])^{\frac{1}{2}}||g_{n_k}||_{\infty}$

Comment: $\Leftrightarrow ||g_{n_k}||_{\infty}\geq 1$ (Because $||g_{n_k}||_2 = \sqrt{2\pi}$). Wouldn't this mean, that the supremum never surpasses 1 and therefore can't converge?

Comment: Yes the inequality itself is sufficient. I just wanted to point out that more is true with the operator norm actually being **equal** to that and that this holds for all $1\leq p<q\leq\infty$.

Comment: Okay, then I hope my answer is correct. Thank you again! You were of great help.